# How can I access properties of dynamic object deserialized from a string using System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-5

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public static dynamic StringToObject(string str) {
    dynamic JsonObjectFromString = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(str);
    System.Console.WriteLine(JsonObjectFromString) // this line show correct json object with a correct type
    System.Console.WriteLine(JsonObjectFromString["cookies"]) // this line will error
    return JsonObjectFromString;
}
```

Basically when I try to access any property of dynamically deserialized object, my program errors. Is there any way to use `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` dynamically?

The string is basically from httpbin.

```
{
  "cookies": {}
}
```

Btw this doesn't happen with NewtonSoft.Json.

Error:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement.this[int]' has some invalid arguments
         at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String )
         at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
         at myNamespace.myClass.StringToObject() in D:\lesha\screener\src\StringToObject.cs:line 12
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
```

Comment: `JsonObjectFromString.cookies`? Also, what is the error?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski edited the question, `JsonObjectFromString.cookies` still errors the same.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, when trying to reference specific elements of a json string without deserializing into a strongly typed object, you do not want to fully deserialize the object since you only use a subset of the data.  In these cases, use the [`JsonDocument.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument.parse?view=net-5.0) API:

```
var json = "{\"cookies\": { \"id\": 1 } }";

var options = new JsonDocumentOptions { AllowTrailingCommas = true };

using var document = JsonDocument.Parse(json, options);
Console.WriteLine(document.RootElement.GetProperty("cookies"));
```

---

If you absolutely want to use dynamic, there is no way to retrieve part of the structure since the underlying type, `JsonElement`, does not contain a Runtime binder that allows you to walk the object.  As a result, you have two options: you can either cast the dynamic to `JsonElement`, or you can directly deserialize to `JsonElement`.  This allows you to use the `GetProperty` method.

```
var str = "{\"cookies\": { \"id\": 1 } }";
var JsonObjectFromString = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(str);
Console.WriteLine(JsonObjectFromString);
Console.WriteLine(((JsonElement)JsonObjectFromString).GetProperty("cookies"));
```

Comment: Few more questions then. Why exactly do I not want that? Why should I use JsonDocument instead? Is there any way to get properties from `JsonObjectFromString`?

Comment: @ColdHands I apologize for making assumptions.  I've clarified my explanation and added an alternative.  But the short answer is that no, as your code is currently written, you cannot retrieve properties from JsonObjectFromString while it is a dynamic.

Comment: Thank you so much, its very detailed and informative!

Comment: Happy to help!!